# Creating PDF file in java using PDDocument results in corrupted PDF files

Tags: java, file, pdf, pdfbox

I'm trying to create temporary `PDF` files in Java using `PDDocument`. I'm employing the following method to create a temporary `PDF` file.

```
/* Create a temporary PDF file.*/
private File createPdf(String fileName) throws IOException {
    final PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
    final File file = File.createTempFile(fileName, ".pdf");
    //write it
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
    bw.write("This is the temporary pdf file content");
    bw.close();
    document.save(file);        
    document.close();
    return file;
}
```

This is the test.

```
@Test
public void testCreateAndMergePdfs() throws IOException {
    Collection<File> pdfs = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(createPdf("File1"), createPdf("File2")));
    assertFalse(CollectionUtils.isEmpty(pdfs));
    PdfPrintPojo pdfPrintPojo = new PdfPrintPojo(pdfs);
    File mergedFile = service.createAndMergePDFs(pdfPrintPojo, "Merged");
    assertNotNull(mergedFile);
    List<File> list = new ArrayList<>(pdfs);
    File file1 = list.get(0);
    File file2 = list.get(1);
    assertTrue(FileUtils.contentEquals(file1, file2));
}
```

What I'm trying to do here is to create and merge two `PDF` files. When I run the test, it creates two `PDF` files in the `temp` folder, for example, `\AppData\Local\Temp\File16375814641476797612.pdf` and `\AppData\Local\Temp\File24102718409195239661.pdf` and the merged file at `\AppData\Local\Temp\Merged_merged_3755858389884894769.pdf`. But the test fails at
 `assertTrue(FileUtils.contentEquals(file1, file2));`
When I try to open the `PDF` files in the `temp` folder, it says that the `PDF` is corrupted. Also, I have no idea why the files are not being saved as `File1` and `File2`. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Where is your createAndMergePDFs method ?

Comment: @Mak It's in a service class, I didn't think that'd be too important here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [Apache PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/cookbook/documentcreation.html) tutorial, I managed to create a working PDF file(s). The method was changed as follows.

```
/* Create a temporary PDF file.*/
private File createPdf(String fileName) throws IOException {
    // Create a document and add a page to it
    final PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
    PDPage page = new PDPage();
    document.addPage(page);

    // Create a new font object selecting one of the PDF base fonts
    PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD;

    // Start a new content stream which will "hold" the to be created content
    PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);

    // Define a text content stream using the selected font, moving the cursor and drawing the text "Hello World"
    contentStream.beginText();
    contentStream.setFont(font, 12);
    contentStream.newLineAtOffset(100, 700);
    contentStream.showText("Hello World");
    contentStream.endText();

    // Make sure that the content stream is closed:
    contentStream.close();

    // Save the results and ensure that the document is properly closed:
    File file = File.createTempFile(fileName, ".pdf");
    document.save(file);
    document.close();
    return file;
}
```

As for the test, I took the approach of using `PDDocument` to load the files, then extract data as String using `PDFTextStripper` and using assertions on those Strings.

```
 @Test
public void testCreateAndMergePdfs() throws IOException {
    Collection<File> pdfs = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(createPdf("File1"), createPdf("File2")));
    assertFalse(CollectionUtils.isEmpty(pdfs));
    PdfPrintPojo pdfPrintPojo = new PdfPrintPojo(pdfs);
    File mergedFile = service.createAndMergePDFs(pdfPrintPojo, "Merged");
    assertNotNull(mergedFile);
    List<File> list = new ArrayList<>(pdfs);

    /* Load the PDF files and extract data as String. */
    PDDocument document1 = PDDocument.load(list.get(0));
    PDDocument document2 = PDDocument.load(list.get(1));
    PDDocument merged = PDDocument.load(mergedFile);

    PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
    String file1Data = stripper.getText(document1);
    String file2Data = stripper.getText(document2);
    String mergedData = stripper.getText(merged);

    /* Assert that data from file 1 and 2 are equal with each other and merged file. */
    assertEquals(file1Data, file2Data);
    assertEquals(file1Data + file2Data, mergedData);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you compare the file contents is a bit different, Could you try with below,

```
@Test
public void testCreateAndMergePdfs() {
    Assert.assertEquals(FileUtils.readLines(file1), FileUtils.readLines(file2));
}
```

Or you can try

```
    byte[] file1Bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("Path to File 1"));
    byte[] file2Bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("Path to File 2"));

    String file1 = new String(file1Bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    String file2 = new String(file2Bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    assertEquals("The content in the strings should match", file1, file2);
```

Or

```
    File file1 = new File(file1);
    File file2 = new File(file2);
    assertThat(file1).hasSameContentAs(file2);
```

Comment: It gave assertion error. I managed to get the PDFs merged and working somehow, now I need to make sure that contents of the merged file equal to that of file1 and file2. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you Check from above, Just take content as a string from both the file and check with merged file content as string. Or  user hasSameContentAs method

Comment: Managed to fix it using PDFTextStripper to extract data from the PDFs, as Strings and the used assertions on those Strings.

Comment: Good. If above answer been useful for you then please upvote and accept it.